# WPF textblock text and DataTrigger

Tags: wpf

I have a `TextBlock` named `Price`. I have a `DataTrigger` that works.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{common:ComparisonBinding DataContext.Discount,GT,0}" Value="{x:Null}">
    <DataTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Text" TargetName="price">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Run>Value1</Run>
                <Run>Value2</Run>
            </Setter.Value>                   
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger.Setters>
</DataTrigger>
```

So this means that if `Discount is > 0` it should display this as `Text.However` run inside this doesnt work. I need bind because I need different text style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error in xaml and @BasBrekelmans said, your trying to assign a `Run` element to a property that expects a `string`.

For your requirement just use a `MultiBinding` with a `StringFormat` to format your bound value's to the required format.

something like:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{common:ComparisonBinding DataContext.Discount,GT,0}"
              Value="{x:Null}">
    <Setter TargetName="price"
            Property="Text">
      <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Some Custom Formatted Text Value1: {0} and Value2: {1}">
          <Binding Path="BindingValue1" />
          <Binding Path="BindingValue2" />
        </MultiBinding>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

If it's the visual Style of the `TextBlock` you're trying to tweak with inline Binding's yeh you're better off modifying your control's Template with a better element than a single `TextBlock` to allow that.

However you could use a work-around by using a converter and applying your `DataTrigger.Setter` to the `TextBlock.Tag`

say something like:

```
public class TextBlockInlineFormatConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    if (values.Length < 3)
      return null;
    TextBlock textblock = values[0] as TextBlock;
    if (textblock == null)
      return null;
    textblock.ClearValue(TextBlock.TextProperty);
    textblock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Some text ") { Foreground = Brushes.Tomato });
    textblock.Inlines.Add(new Run(values[1].ToString()) { Foreground = Brushes.Blue });
    textblock.Inlines.Add(new Run(" and Some other text ") { Foreground = Brushes.Tomato });
    textblock.Inlines.Add(new Run(values[2].ToString()) { Foreground = Brushes.Blue, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
    return textblock.Tag;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

and usage:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{common:ComparisonBinding DataContext.Discount,GT,0}"
              Value="{x:Null}">
    <!-- Note the setter is on Tag and not Text since we modify the Text using Inlines within the converter -->
    <Setter TargetName="price"
            Property="Tag">
      <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TextBlockInlineFormatConverter}"
                      Mode="OneWay">
          <Binding Path="."
                   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
          <Binding Path="BindingValue1" />
          <Binding Path="BindingValue2" />
        </MultiBinding>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

use the work-around only if you're restricted from modifying the control's template tbh.

Comment: that was really smart dude:) thank you.However because of time pressure i added a second textblock with empty text and with the trigger i change its text.I am not sure which is more efficient though.

Answer (score 1):

The collection of `Run` items cannot be applied to the `Text` property, which is a string. The correct property is `Inlines`.

Unfortunately, this property does not have a setter, there should be a different way of solving this, e.g. with a `ContentControl` with two `TextBlock`s in a `StackPanel`.